# Добавление поста в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Проктикуюсь в самостоятельном создании небольшого блога.
Проблема в том что нет добавления записи в БД.

Данные в значения прокидываются  здесь .Проверил отладочной функцией

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`title`, `texton`, `img`) VALUES('$title','$texton','$img')";
```

Но самой отправки в БД не происходит. Не вижу где может быть промах.Прошу помощи.Спасибо

```
         Логика отправления в БД
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../DB.php';


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['button-post']))  {

  $title = trim( $_POST['title']);
  $texton = trim( $_POST['texton']);
$img = $_POST['img'];

  $error ='';

  if (strlen($title) <= 2 ) {
    $error = 'Заголовок должен иметь хотя-бы 2 символа';
  }
  elseif (strlen($texton)<= 5 )  {
    $error = 'У текста должно быть хоть какое-то содержание';
  }

  else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`title`, `texton`, `img`) VALUES('$title','$texton','$img')";

    $query = $connect->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute([$title,$texton,$img]);
    
 }
}
```

Форма заполнения на всякий случай.

```
<form action="addPost_form.php" method="post" class="row justify-content-center">
        <h2>Добавление статьи</h2>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4 err">
            <p><?=$error?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-6">
          <label for="title">Заголовок</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-8">
          <label for="texton">Содержание</label>
          <textarea type="text" name="texton" id="texton" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">
              <input name="img" type="file" class="form-control" id="img">
          </div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">

    </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="button-post">Добавить</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: А суть этого выражения `execute([$title,$texton,$img])` ты понимаешь?

Comment: Насколько я знаю это запуск запроса на его выполенение с конкретными в нем данными. А команда >prepare это подготовка запроса в выполнению

Comment: должно быть VALUES(?,?,?)

Comment: плюс настроить ПДО чтобы сообщал об ошибках

Comment: прям заметил, большинство любит тупо лепить кавычки куда не попадя и попадается на этом https://phpize.online/?phpses=fdbc669630e9483aefbecaf1326114a5&sqlses=b79a112acee29b9a5b4dc3ecbf534980&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Настройка как в вопросе на который переправили очень помогла.Спасибо большое.Ошибка сразу себя показала и моментом решилась

Answer (score -1):

Почитайте про PDO в PHP, и как с ним правильно работать. [Вот, хорошая документация](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/), или конкретно, как [добавлять данные в таблицу](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/php-pdo-insert/).

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`title`, `texton`, `img`) VALUES (:title, :texton, :img)";

$query = $connect->prepare($sql);

$query->execute([
    'title' => $title,
    'texton' => $texton,
    'img' => $img
]);
```

Comment: двоеточия потерял в массиве плейсхолдеров

Comment: Точно, спасибо :)

Comment: Забавно, но даже после прочтения туториала, вы сделали неправильно

Comment: Что неудивительно, поскольку документация по ссылке оставляет желать лучшего

Comment: Ну это не помогло, по прежнему данные отправляются просто в пустоту. Я кстати не особо заметил разницу в отправке.То есть в значения я сразу подставлял заполненные данные,а тут в зарпосе на выполнение идет присвоение.В этом и все разница насколько я понял.Я самоучка,мне долго еще учить и усваивать.Но тут что-то не могу второй день найти ошибку и сюда обратился. Ни у кого нет вариатов что может быть не так?

Comment: @Jean-Claude а зачем prepare-то 2 раза? :)

Comment: @Ипатьев скопировал блок не задумываясь